# How can I redirect a URL to another domain?

Tags: url, redirect

I want `foo.example.horse/short` to redirect to the external URL `https://some.long.org/url/that/i/want/to/redirect_to`. Is there a simple way to do this from Joomla, or do I have to edit the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpublish /short so that it 404s, and then use the redirects manager.
(Components > Redirects).

Details : https://docs.joomla.org/Help37:Components_Redirect_Manager